# can we run kernel as an application, if we can load the kernel program into the address space

Tags: operating-system

It sounds stupid, but is it possible to load any kernel program as an application on already running OS (not as virtual machine).

Like if we load the program into the process address space and run it.

Answer (score 1):

> [..] is it possible to load **any** kernel program as an application on already running OS [..]

No, since a kernel usually contains code to manage system resources, but the host kernel is already managing these. So this either leads to catastrophic failure, or - because we have memory protection and privilege levels and such - to access violations:

As a small example: Probably all kernels need to configure the [interrupt service](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Service_Routines) configuration of the underlying hardware (to get a timer tick, for example).

On x86, this is done by creating an **interrupt descriptor table** and loading the address of that table using the [`lidt`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_156.html) instruction. When issued in an application process (which the host kernel will have running in [ring 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), the least privileged level) the processor will refuse to execute that instruction, because it may only be issued in ring 0, and instead generate an **general protection fault**. The host kernel will be called to handle that situation (because when *that* kernel started it registered an interrupt descriptor table for exactly that purpose). The only way for the host kernel to react to that situation is to abort the process that caused the access violation, because otherwise it would risk system stability and integrity.

Similar issues arise when dealing with segmentation, paging, accessing memory mapped devices and access to peripherals in general.

That said, it is possible to create a kernel that can be run as a user space process, an example that I personally have worked with is [RODOS](http://www.dlr.de/irs/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-5976/9736_read-19576/), which can be run as a Linux process. To make this possible it is necessary to split hardware dependent stuff (which is a large portion) from the independent code (like scheduling, interprocess communication, ...) and provide stubs that reuse functionality of the host operating system to simulate some sort of hardware. (Of course, a such prepared kernel can only run on the host system if it is compiled for that use. You cannot use the same binary as you would use on raw hardware.)